# Subquery in FROM clause using information_schema.tables

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'am trying to get all tables from a database where table name contains 'logs' and get the sum last value in each table of a column named flag.

Query I tried:

```
Select SUM(flag) FROM (SELECT table_name 
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'db_test' AND table_name like '%logs') as c ORDER BY id DESC Limit 1;
```

But I'am having an issue with the subquery, I think the whole query is wrong.

Comment: You need to use dynamic sql for this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: I think you're right, I'am trying but I'am still unable to complete the query. I tried the following: ``` 

I'am trying to get all tables from a database where table name contains 'logs' and get the sum last value in each table of a column named flag.

Query I tried:

PREPARE ST FROM 'Select SUM(flag) FROM (SELECT table_name 
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = ''db_test'' AND table_name like ''%logs'') as c ORDER BY id DESC Limit 1';EXECUTE ST; ``` But I got the following error: Unknown column 'flag' in 'field list'. Although the flag column exists. @P.Salmon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have broken this down into baby steps - nothing to stop you adjusting to taste.

```
drop table if exists onelog,twolog;
create table onelog (id int,flag int);
create table twolog (id int,flag int);

insert into onelog values (1,10),(2,1);
insert into twolog values (1,20),(2,1);


set @sql = 
(
select group_concat(
        concat('select id,flag from ' 
        ,tname, ' where id = (select max(id) from ', tname, ') union all'
        )
        )
from
(
select table_name tname from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%log' and table_schema = 'sandbox'
) s
) 
;
set @sql = substring(@sql,1, length(@sql) - 10);
set @sql = replace(@sql,'union all,','union all ');
set @sql = concat('select sum(flag) from (', @sql , ' ) s');

#select @sql;

prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;

+-----------+
| sum(flag) |
+-----------+
|         2 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and your explanation it worked!